# Is there any possibilities to call the f1() function from outside of the closure in javascripot

Tags: javascript, function, closures

```
function mainFunc(){
  function f1(){
    alert("f1");
  }
  function f2(){
    alert("f2");
  }
}

function myFun(){
  var data = f1();
}
```

Is there any possibilities to call the f1() function from outside of the closure in javascript.

Comment: Not as written (unless you add a breakpoint with a debugger and then leak it). The `f1` variable is only accessible locally.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? This is against the principle of closure. 
Anyways, you can add those functions in prototype of `mainFunc` and access it from outside. But `var data = f1();`? I dont think so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an object using `mainFunc` you can access the methods inside.

```js
function mainFunc(){
  this.f1 = function (){
    alert("f1");
  }
  this.f2 = function(){
    alert("f2");
  }
}

function myFun(){
  var mainObj = new mainFunc();
  var data = mainObj.f1();
}

myFun();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning an object that can still access the function defined in `mainFunc`'s closure!

A little messy, but hope it helps:

```
function mainFunc(){
  function f1(){
    alert("f1");
  }
  function f2(){
    alert("f2");
  }

  return {
    f1 : f1,
    f2 : f2
  };
}


function myFun(){
  var data = mainFunc().f1();
}
```

The idea behind closures is protection while providing access to values in the closure's scope.

Check out previous threads if you haven't already.
I'm fond of this epic answer:
[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
var mainFunc = new mainFunc();
function mainFunc(){
  this.f1 = f1;
  this.f2 = f2;
  function f1(){
    alert("f1");
  }
  function f2(){
    alert("f2");
  }
}

function myFun(){
  var data = mainFunc.f1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to pass the function out or make it accessible some way

There are numerous ways you can do this.

Here is an example of using a callback function. So passing in a function as a parameter to `mainFunc`. The function you pass in is itself expecting two functions `f1` anf `f2` to be passed to it.

```
function mainFunc(cb){
  var f1 = function(){
    console.log("f1");
  }
  var f2 = function(){
    console.log("f2");
  }

  cb(f1, f2);
}

//this example uses an anonymous function as a callback
mainFunc(function(fnA, fnB){
    fnA();
    fnB();
})

//this example uses your named function myFun as a callback
function myFun(fnA, fnB){
    fnA();
    fnB();
}
mainFunc(myFun);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [`Function.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) , [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```js
function mainFunc(){
  function f1(){
    alert("f1");
  }
  function f2(){
    alert("f2");
  }
}

function myFun(){
  var f1 = "";
  var res = mainFunc.toString().split("\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    if (res[i].indexOf("f1") !== -1) {
      f1 += res[i].trim();
    }
    if (res[i].indexOf("}") !== -1 
        && res[i -1].indexOf("f1") !== -1) {
      f1 += res[i].trim();
    }
  };
  f1 = new Function("(" + f1 + "())");
  f1();
}

myFun();
```